# Defining classes in modules with the Ruby C API

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I am trying to define a class inside a module with the Ruby C API. However, the way I have seen this done all over the net doesn't seem to work for me. Specifically, the top-level module gets created but the class can't be found inside the module. Here's my C file:

```
#include <ruby.h>

static VALUE mTree;
static VALUE cNode;

VALUE hello_world(VALUE klass)
{
    return rb_str_new2("hello world");
}

void Init_tree()
{
  mTree = rb_define_module("Tree");
  cNode = rb_define_class_under(mTree, "Node", rb_cObject); 
  rb_define_method(cNode, "hello_world", hello_world, 0);
}
```

Here's my extconf.rb:

```
require 'mkmf'
create_makefile('tree')
```

Here's my test script:

```
require 'tree'
puts Tree        # => Tree
puts Tree::Node  # => uninitialized constant Tree::Node (NameError)
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is strange, your example works for me:

```
→ ruby extconf.rb     
creating Makefile
→ make          
linking shared-object tree.bundle
→ irb
>> $:<<'.'
=> [...]
>> require 'tree'
=> true
>> Tree
=> Tree
>> Tree.class
=> Module
>> Tree::Node.class
=> Class
>> Tree::Node.new.hello_world
=> "hello world"
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you running ? I am using ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-09-23 revision 33323) [x86_64-darwin11.0.0].

Comment: Worked for me as well. I'm on Ruby 1.9.2-p0.

Comment: @louism ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]

Comment: I don't know what happened, now it seems to work (on both 1.9.2 and 1.9.3). Must've been some weird error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
require_relative 'tree'
```